# Download Apk inside my apk without user interaction

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I made an android application inside that i have put an apk file in "res/raw" folder now what i want when i am installing my apk the apk inside the raw folder also install without clicking once more on install button. If it possible by writing my own package manager or package installer please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spyware? Malware? Even if it is not, it might be flagged as such if you have nested APKs.

You can't install without user interaction unless you have system or root permissions. This is a good thing too. If you are building your own firmware, and distributing to limited devices, you can sign your app with the platform key and be able to install packages directly. There are multiple questions about this, but generally you use one of the hidden (from SDK apps) `installPackage()` methods of `PackageManager`.

Comment: can we call this function installPackage() withour rooting the device?

Comment: Yes, if your app is signed with the platform certificate or installed in `/system/app`. Otherwise, no.

Comment: how to sign app with platform.. is any special way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to Root your phone to do this.

The main question is why you would want to.

Comment: I enable Kiosk Feature in my app. so I want to do it without user interaction.. can anyone help.